# C++ ifstream working when not existing file and not working if existing file

Tags: c++, ifstream

i wrote a code and it works perfect. But after 1 week i opened it again and i've got a very interesting probelem, so here is:

```
ifstream file;
file.open("bemenet.txt");

int i = -1;

while (i < SOR)
{
    i++;
    file >> termekek[i].termek;
    file >> termekek[i].ara;
    file >> termekek[i].darab;


}

file.close();
```

in this case `bemenet.txt` is exist, the program is compilated and when i try to run: i've got the error code: 0xC0000005

another case is `bemenet2.txt` is not exist, the program is compilated and works, but ofc when i want to see what data i've got from files it runs to infinite loop.

can you help me? i don't know what would i do...

Comment: Hmm, how is declared `termemek`? I would bet that you have an array overflow there...

Comment: <code>
struct TERMEKEK
{
    string termek;
    int ara;
    int darab; 

};

TERMEKEK termekek[SOR];
</code>

i know... it not the best nameing... but when i wrote the program it works..

Comment: There is no testing for successful read or even successful file open. `i` is incremented before use, allowing easy buffer overrun.

Comment: when i run for bemenet.txt  (the file is exist) i've got the error code when i run the program, but for bemenet2.txt (wich is do not exist) the program it runs the menu is appears ( i wrote the menus)

Comment: @user4581301 the error code appears immediatly when i start the program

Comment: [Reading from an istream without checking the result](http://kayari.org/cxx/antipatterns.html#istream-check) is usually a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for something like this:

```
ifstream file;
file.open("bemenet.txt");

TERMEK t ;
std::vector<TERMEK > termekek ;

while (file >> t.termek >> t.ara >> t.darab  )
    termekek.push_back(t) ;
```

Comment: `vector` is the better solution for this. Don't know why I didn't mention it. Can I talk you into putting the braces in around the while loop body?

Comment: You do not need brtaces, but they make no harm and make code clearer

Answer (score 1):

```
ifstream file;
file.open("bemenet.txt");

int i = 0;

while ((i < SOR) && file >> termekek[i].termek >> termekek[i].ara >> termekek[i].darab  )
{
    i++;
}

file.close();
```

`while (file >> termekek[i].termek >> termekek[i].ara >> termekek[i].darab)` will test just about every IO and conversion condition you will care about--open failure, end of file, data conversion failure, sundry IO read errors--thanks to `iostream`'s boolean operator  and `(i < SOR) &&` prevents overflow. Note `i` is now incremented after read and before the next test removing the possibility of the off-by-one error allowing `i` to get past `SOR`.

Comment: Seriously consider marom's suggestion of a vector if allowed by your coding standard or assignment. It reduces the possibility of a lot of bugs.

Comment: probably you are right, but tomorrow i will need to presentation for my teacher, so i do not have enough time to rewrite all code...
I wrote a program like vending machine, you can buy, you can go to admin mode and you have a lot of statistics...